# Creating a C++11 std::function<> with state

Tags: c++

what is the best way to create a C++11 `std::function<>` with state?

In plain C++98, I would create a functor struct that inherited from `std::unary_function<>` or `std::binary_function<>`. So given the following functor, how do I create a `std::function<int(int)>` from the following functor?

```
struct Functor
{
    int x;
    Functor(int val) : x(val) {}

    int operator()(int val) { return val + x; }
};

int main()
{
    Functor f(10);
    int x = f(30);
}
```

Note that the code above is a great simplification of what I need. Actually, the functor is configured with multiple parameters and reads data from a file (where each record is more complex than an int). Is there a solution that is closer to using functors than using lambdas?

**Edit**: Clarification

Comment: @LaszloPapp std::bind is part of the C++11 standard, and is useful for when you are actually binding a function that is somewhere else in the code, one that you really want to be there. The purpose of lambda was to avoid having to write functors externally when they are only going to be invoked from one place.

Comment: bind was part of tr1 and part of boost, so it has been around for ages. It is a new "library" feature of C++11 as to being in the formal standard as std::bind. lambda is a completely new language feature. However you don't have to use it, bind is still there.

You said in your comment "You will need to use lambda" which is not true, you can use lambda now and it looks cleaner as you show how the function call is made (as in my answer) and I presume can insert a breakpoint there too which will make it easier to debug should something bad happen in this call.

Comment: @Manuel: Please do not modify the question radically next time after the good answers given. IMHO, a new thread should have been opened. This is not so respectful towards people already giving valid answers to a question because it forces them to further maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use functors and classes in C++11, and in fact `std::bind` and `std::function` are now part of the C++11 standard, whereas previously they were part of the boost library and supported in tr1 or as extensions by various standard libraries. (Not compilers, they compiled already by the C++98/03 standard, but they were added as a library feature).

Lambdas are a new language feature, which are very useful when you really want a 1 or 2 line expression in an algorithm like `sort` or `remove_if` where a loop is inappropriate.

In your case, whilst you can write it with a lambda, if your logic is as complex as you make out, you probably don't want to use one in this instance for the sake of breaking up the logic of your code. You might still use a lambda to create a std::function out of this.

You might possibly even want to go down the even older "school" of using polymorphism here, i.e. passing in an object that has a function with a signature, and use that as the callback. It will certainly be easier to maintain the lifetimes of any objects this way.

Now, let's assume your object wants a `callback` function which essentially takes an `int` parameter somewhere and returns an int.

**std::bind**

What `bind` does is actually add extra parameters to a function, but that function must return an int. What it can do is be a class member function or take extra parameters.

If it is a class member you need an object to call it on.

```
std::bind( &MyClass::myFunction, myClassInstance, a, std::placeholders::_1 , b);
```

`myClassInstance` can be a reference-wrapper or pass-by-value or a pointer or a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` of an object to your type. A reference-wrapper is a special class that contains a reference due to the fact that automatic template deduction will not be able to know whether you actually want to be passing a reference or by-value.
Be careful of using reference-wrappers. The reference must still be valid at the point the function is called, and many hard-to-find bugs have occurred this way. In fact in its early days I rejected using bind and callbacks but it was so hard to trace bugs like these.

The `placeholders::_1` tells the `std::function` where to put the `int` parameter it is passing. As I said, it can take extra parameters, but one of them will be your int. Essentially it means "put your int value here". `a` and `b` there are other parameters that need to be passed into this function and are supplied by the binder.

**Lambdas**

Lambdas do provide an alternative syntax to your bind in that you will actually invoke the call to your function in there. I am assuming that, given the complexity, you are going to write a function and a class somewhere and you just want to use a lambda to bind the callback to it.

In that case, you put in the square brackets of your lambda what is known as its "captures". These are like the other parameters of your bind.

```
std::function< int(int) > myFunc = [ &myClassInstance, a, b ]( int x )
{
    return myClassInstance.myFunction( a, x, b );
};
```

The captures here say that myClassInstance is a reference but the other two are by value. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda for information about capture syntax.

Comment: "Lambdas are a new language feature, which are very useful when you really want a 1 or 2 line expression in an algorithm like sort or remove_if where a loop is inappropriate" -> Lamdas in C++ are explicitly not like in python where it is enforced by the language to be a single statement. In fact, in most cases I have been working with, it is not a one-liner just for the record. I think they are useful for multi-line statements as well.

Comment: Also, please give more authoritative links than "cppreference". It is known for being not-so-good at times.

Comment: It seems good enough here to show you lambda capture syntax, which I found, when I first learnt C++11, to be sorely under-documented.

Comment: As for more than one-or-two line lambdas, just like any other loop body or other part of the code, if they become extensively long, it probably means your code starts to look overly complex to follow.

In the case of this user, he said he wanted it to be relatively complex, which suggests he may want to write a function or class to manage the complexity.

The lambda is useful in turning that function or class to a simple "function" to pass as a callback.

Comment: I think you are seeing the world black and white: i.e. 1-2 lines or nothing. I would like to repeat that it is not enforced by the language for a reason. Lambdas are useful, just as any functions or methods when you do not need to call it from more places, and it is not a god functionality, but that does not mean only 1-2 lines are not god functionality. Re your other comment: it is not about capture syntax or not. My comment was specifically about *cppreference* which is known for being flaky at times. Please use the standard next time (or even for udpating this).

Comment: It's not really about the number of lines but the complexity of the lambda and whether it makes the code look cleaner to have the code inline or put it elsewhere.

The problem with the old system was that you had to either create a functor even when not appropriate or use a bind (often boost or std::tr1) which looks ugly.

It looks much tidier to show how the function is called than the reall ugly bind syntax.

Comment: I am not sure I follow why bind is ugly... :-)

Comment: It is not immediately intuitive what it does. std::bind( &MyClass::myFunction, myClassInstance, a, std::placeholders::_1 , b); In one glance can you see it is actually invoking myClassInstance.myFunction( a, x, b ) for input x? Maybe, because you are probably used to them. But still not as intuitive as the lambda syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest to use a lambda expression for this:

```
std::function<int(int)> f = [](int n) { return n + 30; }
```

You can also use `std::bind`:

```
std::function<int(int)> f = std::bind(std::plus<int>, std::placeholders::_1, 30);
```

In both cases, the `30` is just an example that could be replaced by a captured variable (make sure to change the capture specification in the lambda to `[=]`, though), and you would be better off using type `auto` to avoid a potentially expensive creation of a `function` object when you only need *some* callable type.

Comment: In case of `std::bind`, it is better to use `auto f = std::bind( etc.. );` But then that is true for lambda also. So the point is : `std::function` should *not* used merely because it can be used.

Comment: @Nawaz: which is exactly what Kerrek also wrote. I am not sure what point you are trying to make.

Comment: And the advantage of the lambda is specifically that the syntax is a lot cleaner, i.e you can see immediately what it does.

Answer (score 2):

Use Lambdas:

```
 int x = 0;
 std::function<int (int)> add = [x](int val) { return  x + val; }
 auto add2 = [x](int val) { return  x + val; }
```

Here, the variables the lambda has access to are in the square brackets. x is passed as a copy. You can also pass a state as a reference by prefixing it with an '&' and capture 'this'